# Why can I capture rb_warn messages on $stderr only once?

Tags: ruby, openssl

Due to a bad decision on OpenSSL's part that affected the Ruby bindings, the only way to check if an OCSP request is signed is by parsing the warning from `OpenSSL::OCSP::Request#verify`. I intercept `$stderr` and read the warning, but if I repeat this process in multiple unit tests, the first error message gets captured every time, even though each intercept uses a new buffer.

As an example, I created this script: `test.rb`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'openssl'
require 'stringio'

def main
  if ARGV[0]
    puts "signed: \n#{signed}"
    puts "unsigned: \n#{unsigned}"
  else
    puts "unsigned: \n#{unsigned}"
    puts "signed: \n#{signed}"
  end
end

def unsigned
  cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
  certid = OpenSSL::OCSP::CertificateId.new cert, cert
  request = OpenSSL::OCSP::Request.new.add_certid certid
  store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new

  capture_stderr { request.verify([], store) }
end

def signed
  key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate(2048)
  cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
  cert.public_key = key.public_key
  cert.sign(key, OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new)
  certid = OpenSSL::OCSP::CertificateId.new OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new, cert

  store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
  store.add_cert cert

  request = OpenSSL::OCSP::Request.new.add_certid certid
  request.sign(cert, key)

  capture_stderr { request.verify([], store) }
end

def capture_stderr
  $stderr = StringIO.new
  result = yield
  [result, $stderr.string]
ensure
  $stderr = STDERR
end

# try `./test.rb` and `./test.rb 1`
main
```

By flipping the order of function calls, I get different results.

```
$ ./test.rb
unsigned:
[false, "./test.rb:22: warning: error:27074080:OCSP routines:OCSP_request_verify:request not signed\n"]
signed:
[false, "./test.rb:38: warning: error:27074080:OCSP routines:OCSP_request_verify:request not signed\n"]
```

and

```
$ ./test.rb 1
signed:
[false, "./test.rb:38: warning: error:27074065:OCSP routines:OCSP_request_verify:certificate verify error\n"]
unsigned:
[false, "./test.rb:22: warning: error:27074065:OCSP routines:OCSP_request_verify:certificate verify error\n"]
```

I imagine that the explanation for this weird behavior probably goes into the C language part of the Ruby stdlib codebase.

Comment: *"...  the only way to check if an OCSP request is signed is by parsing the warning from OpenSSL::OCSP::Request#verify"* - Forgive my ignorance... You can find the source for the OCSP gear in `<openssl src>/apps/ocsp.c`. You can lift/reuse any code you want from the library. The short coming seems to be in Ruby and its inability to provide what you need. OpenSSL does not provide bindings; those are provided by Python, Ruby, PHP, etc. Maybe you should file a bug report against Ruby to get what you need.

Comment: Hmm... hadn't looked there before. But there's no usage of `OCSP_request_verify`. Only the response gets verified. So if it's not even available in the app part, I guess that's a pretty strong message that the OpenSSL authors don't think it's meaningful to verify where requests are coming from. Maybe I need to rethink why I'm doing this (and why the OCSP RFC even defines a SigRequired status).

Comment: If the warning or error message is coming from OpenSSL, then the code can be lifted. OpenSSL provides functions like `OCSP_verify`, `OCSP_BASICRESP_verify` and `OCSP_REQUEST_verify`. Maybe Ruby needs to expose it. Don't take my word on it... `cd <openssl src>` and then perform `grep -IR 'OCSP_*.*verify' *`.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a bug in Ruby's OpenSSL library. It was fixed in the Gem version 2.0.0-beta2: https://github.com/ruby/openssl/commit/9af69abcec15b114d9a0ec3811983fc1d7b5a1dc

Now OpenSSL messages aren't repeatedly leaked to stderr. However, it is now impossible to differentiate between untrusted signatures and missing signatures. Thankfully, I was wrong before and verification does indeed fail for missing signatures.